# Replacing dashes and commas in Java with spaces

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to remove all dashes (-) and commas (,) using the replaceall function in Java. However, I can only remove either the dash, or the comma. How can I fix this?

```
if (numOfViewsM.find()){
    if (numOfViewsM.toString().contains(","))
    {
        numOfViews =Integer.parseInt(numOfViewsM.group(1).toString().replaceAll(",", ""));
    }
    else if (numOfViewsM.toString().contains("-"))
    {
        numOfViews = Integer.parseInt(numOfViewsM.group(1).toString().replaceAll("-", ""));
    }
    else
        numOfViews = Integer.parseInt(numOfViewsM.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[replaceall(regex,
                String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method takes regex. You can do that, using one statement like

```
String output= str.replaceAll("[-,]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
String result = numOfViewsM.replaceAll("[-,]", "");
```

as the first parameter of the `replaceAll()` method is a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Forget `contains()`. use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "adsa-,adsa-,sda";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[-,]", ""));
}
```

O/P :

```
adsaadsasda
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code looks like

```
if string contains ,
   remove , 
   parse
else if string contains -
   remove - 
   parse
else 
   parse
```

As you see all cases exclude each other because of `else if` part which means you will either be able to remove `-` or `,`. You could improve it a little by removing `else` keyword and moving `parse` part after you will *clear* your data like

```
if string contains ,
   remove , 
if string contains -
   remove - 
parse
```

But you shouldn't even check if your text `contains` `,` or `-` in the first place because it will make you traverse over your string once until it finds searched character. You will also need to traverse your second time with `replaceAll` method anyway, so you can change your code into

```
remove , 
remove - 
parse
```

or even better

```
remove , OR - 
parse
```

Since `replaceAll` takes `regex` you can write `-` OR `,` condition as `-|,` or even `[-,]` (using [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html))

```
replaceAll("-|,","")
```

But if your title is correct you may not want to remove these characters by replacing them with empty string, but rather with space

```
replaceAll("-|,"," "); //replace with space, not with empty string
//               ^^^
```